# Google Cloud Function crashing with error: Build failed: Build has timed out

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run a deep learning model using Google Cloud functions. Just trying to load it but it gives the following error while deployment:

```
Build failed: Build has timed out.
```

I just load a bunch of files for the deep learning model which all total to about 250MB. Pretty sure it is because of the size of the files being loded, but not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The timeout set on GCF build is 5 minutes.

I suspect that your function took more than 5 minutes to compile and deploy and you got `Build failed: Build has timed out.` error.

There are many things that can influence the amount of time something takes to deploy, e.g. if it needs to download an external file and the service hosting that file is slow (your learning model is about 250MB).

Therefore I would recommend to use Cloud Run.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of work to do in Cloud Functions, you shout do that at the time of function invocation.  It sounds like your deployment is instead trying to do that work at build/load time, before the function is deployed.  Without seeing your code, it's not possible to tell.

You should know that Cloud Functions is not a very good product for doing large amounts of computational work.  Even if you defer the work to the time of function invocation, the default timeout is 1 minute, configurable to a maximum of 9 minutes.  If your work could take longer than that, it's definitely not a good fit.

Cloud Run, another serverless product recommended by marian.vladoi here, has similar limits, and it also not suitable for large amounts of work.

Generally speaking, serverless compute products are not good for computationally expensive work.  That's not what they were designed for.  For that, you should consider using something like Compute Engine.  If you need Cloud Functions triggering behavior, you can simply have your function delegate the work to another compute product.

Comment: I don't think the actual function is computationally expensive, loading the files is what takes time. The actual function executes on my machine in <1s. I'll take a look at Cloud Runn/App engine and see if that works, else I'll use something like compute engine.